# How to plot a shapefile in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, shapefile

I have a question regarding plotting a polygon shapefile in matplotlib.
The data I am working with is available [here](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5e0a3fcde4b0b207aa0d794e) (the zip file called Delmarva_PL_House_Final.zip). The polygons coordinates are UTM 18N.

After importing it into geopandas and changing the crs as such:
`df = df.to_crs(epsg=4326)`
I went ahead and plotted the shapefile using the following command:
`df.plot()`
But this is the result I got:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong... you just need to zoom in a bit to be able to actually see the data:

[image]